# Cannot get the value of a textarea via post method

Tags: php, html, http-post

It is a very simple form as in the code below:

```
 <form method="POST" action="news.php?nid=2">
  <textarea id="txtcomment" style="width:100%; height: 70px;" maxlength="300"></textarea><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" class="button" style="float: right; cursor:pointer;" value="Comment">
 </form>
```

but in the news.php i cannot get the value of "txtcomment"

```
 echo $_POST['txtcomment'];
```

it returns nothing...

Comment: Try setting the name attribute of your textarea to txtcomment, not just the id

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because you need to name the textarea:

```
<textarea name="txtcomment"></textarea>
```

The `id` parameter does not have anything to do with how forms work (with the exception of `label`s, but that is not important here).

Answer (score 4):

Specify the name attribute of the textarea.

Answer (score 4):

Add name attribute in textarea

```
<textarea id="txtcomment" name="txtcomment" style="width:100%; height: 70px;" maxlength="300"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to have an attribute name with txtcomment in it, you have an attribute 'id'

Answer (score 4):

You have to define a name attribute (the id attribute is possible but not necessary).

```
<textarea name="txtcomment" ...>
```

Answer (score 4):

textarea  name must be txtcomment not id like

```
<form method="POST" action="news.php?nid=2">
<textarea id="txtcomment" name="txtcomment" style="width:100%; height: 70px;" maxlength="300"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" class="button" style="float: right; cursor:pointer;" value="Comment">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not id="" that names the field in your array, it's name="".

```
<textarea name="txtcomment" id="txtcomment" style="width:100%; height: 70px;" maxlength="300"></textarea><br /><br />
```